# Excel 2013: VBA to find all cells with duplicate ID text and dump cell contents to 2nd sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Not sure that the title is very clear.

Basically, I have about 500 rows in column B of this sheet that contain Nessus vulnerability scan data. The key element is the "Plugin ID: ######" text. A few columns over, that Plugin ID/vuln is tied to a set of hosts.

Some Plugin IDs occur several times throughout the 500 rows, however, as this data is temporal (month to month) as we do new scans, sometimes it is fixed on older hosts but newer hosts for some reason now have that vulnerability, and sometimes it is a mix (several hosts will be fixed, others won't, new hosts come in with same problem).

(B) Plugin ID: 123456 (J) server1, server2, server3

.

.

.

(B) Plugin ID: 123456 (J) server1, server2

I want to have a VBA function that takes the Plugin ID from each cell in column B and searches the remainder of column B for a duplicate, and then copies that Column B cell and its row content from column J for the original and each duplicate to a new sheet, that way I can eyeball the rows and establish what has actually been patched according to Nessus.

As it is, I can sort of do this manually by filtering, but it is slow and onerous.

Where should I start? I always get caught up trying to decide if i I should do old school VBA functions or use some of the newer built in Excel VBA functions and tools.

Answer (score 0):

Why VBA? Just use the COUNTIF to check how many times is the ID repeated and filter the formula column for rows with count > 1. Sort also the ID column so the repeated rows appear next to each other.

e.g.

```
=COUNTIF(B$3:B$7;B3)
```